# Throttling Outgoing HTTP requests

Tags: http, rx-java, vert.x, throttling

I am using vert.x as a server to receive a search request which is then processed on the server to multiple outgoing HTTP requests to various external services.

For asynchronous behavior I have chosen to use RxJava using Vert.x native http client.

Thing is, the services I am using limit me to maximum 1 call per second.

What would be the best/simple way to throttle NIO HTTP outgoing requests?

1. In a single server environment.
2. In a clustered server environment.

Comment: Could you show some code? I don't get why you would go full reactive if you have a bottleneck of one second?

Comment: I am using RxJava because it seems like a more complete solution to asynchronous functional programming than future or promises based API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single server a naive approach to solve your problem would be:

1. Push the request plus an result handler to a queue
2. Have a periodic handler that pops an element from the queue every second and executes the request
3. Call the result handler with the result or error

In a clustered way you could extend the previous concept and wrap it on an event bus address so it would be something like:

1. Send a message to the address with the request and setup a reply handler
2. The service would work as on the previous explanation
3. Instead of calling a handler the service would rely on the message reply handler to pass the result.

Comment: Thanks Paulo for your answer, regarding the cluster part of the answer I'll have to control the consume rate of that message bus queue to match the outgoing call rate limit.