# How to limit parallel http requests in Micronaut Http Client

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, micronaut, reactivex, micronaut-client

I am working on a micronaut project. I am calling some external web services using micronaut declarative http client.

```
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;
import io.reactivex.Single;

    @Client("/external-client") 
    public interface MyClient {

        @Post
        Single<String> submit(String name, int age);
    }
```

What I am doing exactly is whenever i am getting a message from one message queue i am posting that data from queue to the external service. So inside the queue listener i am subscribing this client code.

```
myClient.submit(name,age).subscribe{ success, error -> //... mylogic }
```

Now the problem is external service provider is limited the rate of request in a minute. Now I want to limit the number of request triggering at a time. I am very much new in the rxjava and micronaut application development.What will be the better design for throttle the parallel requests triggered from my application. Is there any RxJava way to limit the requests? or I want to do any configuration change in httpclient configuration. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Throttling Outgoing HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288243/throttling-outgoing-http-requests)

Comment: It's a very similar question. Do you have any example application for my reference. Thank you

Comment: Would limiting the number of threads in the scheduler work? Like the [computation scheduler](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#computation--) limits the amount of threads to the available processors. In other words, whatever streams you schedule in this scheduler won't run as long as threads are not available. Don't use this scheduler for io work. I'm only putting it here as an example of what I meant.

Comment: The answer will probably depend on how you want to handle requests that are created too frequently for the external API to handle. Your choices being: ignore, buffer indefinitely, buffer to a limit.